# Minimum positive eigenvalue (courant fisher theorem)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Assume, $y^TAy \geq 0$ for all $0 \neq y \in R^n$, i.e. ($A$ is symmetric positive semi-definite matrix). Also take $A = B^TB$. Now, let's say there exists $0 \neq x \in R^n$ such that $x^TAx = \|Bx\|^2 > 0$ holds. I want to prove the following if possible: $$x^TAx \geq \lambda_{\min}^+(A) \ \|x\|^2$$

I tried this: I know that by courant fisher theorem, we have $x^TB^TBx \geq \lambda_{\min}^+(B^TB) \ \|x\|^2$ for $x \in \textbf{Range}(B^T)$. Since, we have $\|Bx\|^2 > 0$, this implies $x \notin \textbf{Null}(B)$. Now, can I say $x \in \textbf{Range}(B^T) $ as $\textbf{Null}(B) \ \cap \ \textbf{Range}(B^T) = \{0\}$?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by $\lambda^+_{\min}$?

Comment: I meant minimum positive eigenvalue.

Comment: Then no: the fact that $Bx \neq 0$ (or equivalently, $Ax \neq 0$) is not enough to conclude that $x^TAx \geq \lambda_{\min}^+(A)\|x\|^2$.

Comment: I would recommend that you consider in detail the simple example
$$
A = \pmatrix{1&0\\0&0}.
$$
If you like, you could take $B = A$ and find that $A = B^TB$.

Comment: Thanks. I am looking for a maximum positive constant  $\mu > 0$ such that $x^TAx \geq \mu \|x\|^2$ holds for the $x $ as mentioned.

Comment: If $A$ has a zero eigenvalue, then there is no positive constant $\mu$ such that this holds for all $x^TAx \geq \mu \|x\|^2$ with $Bx \neq 0$

Comment: Since I have $x^TAx > 0$ by assumption for some $x$, I am looking for a positive constant for those $x$.

Comment: And I am telling you that there is no such constant. It's as if someone asked "I know that all of the numbers from the set $S = \{1,1/2,1/3,1/4,\dots\}$ are positive. What is the smallest $\mu > 0$ for which $x \geq \mu$ for every $x \in S$?"

Comment: The words in my earlier comment were a bit scrambled. I meant to say: if $A$ has a zero eigenvalue, then there is no positive constant $\mu$ such that $x^TAx \geq \mu \|x\|^2$ holds for *every* $x$ with $Bx \neq 0$.

Comment: Okay got it. Thanks for the clarification.